# Multi Date picker JS issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-multidatespicker

1. I am using `multidatespicker.js` for datepicker.
2. When I select date first time it is staying on that month only.But
   again if i select another date ,it month is redirecting to current
   date.
3. My problem is that when selecting any date it should stay in that
   month only. I attached [sample example](http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/23/)

Script

```
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
    
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var dates = $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker('getDates');
        alert(dates);
    });
```

Any help is appreciated !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to have a feature like you want, so it behaves correctly. It should be implemented externally, if possible.

Comment: Can you help me,so that i can implement externally.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough knowledge to do this :(

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you use dateFormate with it. e.g.

```
$('#abc').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d", 
});
```

Also use defaultDate with it. It will work fine. e.g.

```
$('#abc').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d", 
    defaultDate:"96-2-25"
});
```